# Get value Before last value with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have query with Entity Frameworks like this:

```
var lastYear = anios.Select(x => x.ID).LastOrDefault();
```

I want to know if it's possible to get value before `LastOrDefault` item.

For example if I have:

2015
2016
2017
2018

I want to get 2017 instead 2018. there is some trick to get this value with EF?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastYear = anios.Select(x => x.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .Take(2).Last();
```

Sorry I dont have exact syntax.... the intent of my answer is to sort descending and take the top two.  Of the two take the second.  You should check the count first of course which my example does not show.

Comment: Try putting .OrderByDescending after .Select(). Sorry I am doing this from memory.